# Xamarin Forms Gif Delay And Black Spots

Tags: xamarin.forms, gif

I'm trying to use a gif as my `Image` Source but I have 2 problems:

The gif is starting some seconds after my application starts

After that, the animation is working but I got some black parts appearing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmhhd.jpg)

My image is placed inside the drawable folder inside the android project.

Comment: The gif file is very resource heavy. Are you using high resolution/too long gif? Besides, in my test, there is no "black part". Did you test any other gifs? Do they have the same "black part"?

Comment: yes, I have another gif and the same problem occurs

Comment: Try to use "ffimageloading" to show gif. `<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage Source="test.gif"/>` Here is the [related API](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API). Besides, if could, please provide a gif sample file.

Comment: Delay in showing gif. My file has 154 KB in size. There is no information regarding .gif size in official documentation. I am using the .gif as loader in my app.